# Simple socket manager

Tags: c#, socket

I just wondered if someone could review this socket class for me.

```
using Apple.Application.Base.Sockets;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Apple.Application.Base.Connection
{
    class SocketManager
    {
        private Socket _serverSocket;
        private SocketSettings _settings;

        public SocketManager(SocketSettings settings)
        {
            _settings = settings;
            _serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            BeginListen();
            BeginAccept();
        }

        public void BeginListen()
        {
            _serverSocket.Bind(_settings.EndPoint);
            _serverSocket.Listen(_settings.SocketBacklog);
        }

        public void BeginAccept()
        {
            _serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(OnAccept), null);
        }

        public void OnAccept(IAsyncResult AsyncResult)
        {
            try
            {
                _settings._log.Info("New connection was received");
                Apple.GetPlayerManager().RegisterNewPlayer();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                _settings._log.Error(exception);
            }
            finally
            {
                BeginAccept();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the `SocketSettings` class:

```
using log4net;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Apple.Application.Base.Sockets
{
    sealed class SocketSettings
    {
        public IPEndPoint EndPoint { get; set; }
        public ushort SocketBacklog { get; set; }
        public ILog _log { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd say, your call to Apple.GetPlayerManager() bothers me. Your socket implementation does not need to know this is a game and it's creating a new player etc. I whould break the relation somehow, passing the payload or event received in your socket to some other service, preferably injected using dependency injection or sth.

This would make your socket class testable on its own (by mockup objects) and other classes much easily.

PS: your SocketSettings class is actually ServerInformation, copy/paste problem I suppose..

Comment: Paste problem yes, for the other advice I would like to know how you suggest I do that.

Comment: sorry, I typed my suggestion perhaps in a rush.. which part is not clear? in summary just think of a service that consumes data coming from your input. That service somehow processes and redirects data to your game manager or sth. this way, both sides are unaware of each other, hence testable on their own.. I may be repeating myyself, so feel free to ask specific points..